# Making a WCF Singleton run for long periods

Tags: wcf, iis-6, singleton, infinite, lifetime

I have a WCF service that runs as a singleton in IIS. The issue with this service is that the worker process recycles in approx. 40 minutes.

Is it possible to make the service run for long periods using IIS settings?
If yes, please let me know some IIS settings.
Or, is there another way to be followed to keep the WCF in IIS alive....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `Idle timeout` to `0` value in advanced settings for application pool

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider hosting the service as a Windows Service instead of IIS. You're kinda fighting the IIS on-demand instantiation lifecycle by configuring the service as a singleton.